# Java split() checking if index equals a value

Tags: java, split

I have a function which gets passed in a string. From that I split the string with

```
String[] info = s.split("\\s+");
```

I then want to see if the first index is a plus sign (+). If i enter in a string: + other stuff it claims that + != +

```
System.out.println("Check if "+ info[0]+ " = +");
if(info[0]=="+") {
    System.out.println("yes");
} else
    System.out.println("no");
```

This is the output i get:

```
Interp> + 
Check if + = + 
no
```

anyone know why this is?

Comment: `.equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing `String`s, always use `String.equals(String str)`. == will compare strings for equal memory identity, `String.equals()` will compare for the same content.

`if(info[0].equals("+")) { do stuff.. }`

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
if(info.length > 0 && "+".equals(info[0])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two `Strings` you should always use `myString.equals(otherstring);`
In your case this could be

```
if(info[0].equalsIgnoreCase("+") {
    System.out.println("yes");
} else
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

These are the possibilities for Strings:

- `string1.equals(string2)`   -> returns boolean
- `string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)`  -> returns boolean
- `string1.compareTo(string2)` -> returns **-1** if string1 comes alphabetically before string2, **0** if both strings are equal, **+1** if string2 comes alphabetically before string1

For explanation: the `==` operator compares the memory reference of the two strings not the content of the strings.